# How to override operator>> to split cin input into array elements

Tags: c++, arrays

I trying to create a class with the operator>> overrided so that the characters from the input are split up and inserted into their own array/list elements. For example:

```
cin >> myobj // say '1234' is entered
```

Would be represented similar to this:

```
cout >> myobj // outputs something like [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I'm not very experienced with C++ and don't if this is incredibly trivial or is just a bad idea for some reason.

Comment: Why not just put them in a string?

Comment: Thia is not a very good place to ask "I have an idea but I don't know where to start" type questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a perfectly reasonable thing to do. One possible way to write the code would be along this general line:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class foo { 
    char a, b, c, d;

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, foo &f) { 
        is.get(f.a);
        is.get(f.b);
        is.get(f.c);
        is.get(f.d);
        return is;
    }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, foo const &f) {
        return os << '[' << f.a << ',' << f.b << ',' << f.c << ',' << f.d << ']';
    }
};

int main() { 
    foo f;
    std::istringstream input("1234");

    input >> f;
    std::cout << f;
}
```